# Table Parameter in MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-workbench

Basically I am trying to refer to my table in mysql function, so that in my query I can say "from x" as in x is a parameter of the function, so that someone can put in the table they want the function to run on.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `somefunction`(t varchar(8), num integer) RETURNS int(8)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE result integer(12);
    DECLARE test varchar(12);
    SET result = 0;
    SET test = t;
    select integer * 5 INTO result from x;
    return result;
    END
```

Basically when I do somefunction(thisisthetableiwant, 5) I get an error saying that it cannot find 'test in field list' so it isn't setting the table to what I put in the parameter, currently I have the part "from x" hardcoded with the table I want and it works but I need to make it so I can have a parameter incase I need to use the function on another table

Comment: can't do it like this. You cannot use a parameter/variable/contents-of-field as an sql keyword. You need to build your query as a string, insert your table name into that, then execute the string.

Comment: e.g. `set foo='users'; select * from @foo` will not work.

Comment: So I've looked at other answers like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549619/mysql-dynamically-build-query-string-in-a-stored-procedure-based-on-logic and it seems that I cannot do that because I am creating a function not a procedure because I have tried creating a concat string and I get the "error 1336: dynamic sql is not allowed in stored function or trigger sql statement"

Comment: But your function can call a stored procedure! Yeah, that's ugly.