# How to use IF condition in Stored Procedure Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my Stored procedure Query. Here if typee is existing it should add the 2nd condition or it should not add. 
My table structure is like this

```
|id | name | typee |is_primary|
|1  |IND   |0      |1         |
|2  |SRIL  |1      |0         |
```

My Stored Procedure query is following

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testIfCondition`(IN countryId int(11),IN typee INT(11),IN is_primary INT(11),
out name VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
     select name from country where id = id
        if typee != 0 then
          and typee= typee 
        end if;
       if is_primary !=0 then
          and primary = primary 
        end if;
END
```

In the above query which ever is having values has to get execute. If anyone know please help me out in this. When i am trying it is giving some syntax error. Please tell me correct syntax to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: What are `typee` and `trypes`?  Where do they come from?  What do you mean "*if it is existing*"?  What do you mean "*it should add the 2nd condition*"?  What on Earth should this sproc actually *do*?  Voting to close as one of the least clear questions I've ever read.

Comment: Hope now it ll be clear for you !

Comment: By changing `trypes` to another `typee` so now you're comparing it with itself?  No, I can't say that's made it any more clear *at all*.  If anything, it's now even less clear—something I didn't imagine was possible.  Try answering the questions I posed in my previous comment: that might help.

Comment: Some times typee may come as null. So if it is coming as null it should end with where id = id.. If typee is not null it has to add another condition and typee = typee

Comment: select * from country where id = id and typee = typee  here id and typee are dynamic.Some values will come while calling the stored procedure

Comment: What's the point of comparing `typee = typee` if you know it isn't NULL? It will always be TRUE for non-null `typee`.

Comment: from UI i can select that typee. That is not required field. So if it is coming it has use the condition. If null is coming it should not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you could add more condition using the `IF` statement.
You can probably select it twice or more and add it to a `temporary table`, for example like this:

First create the `temporary table`

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (
    ID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(250),
    Typee INT
)
```

Then insert the first `SELECT` result to the `@tempTable`

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable
SELECT * FROM country WHERE id = countryId
```

Then use the condition to check if the `typee` is `NULL` or not

```
IF typee IS NOT NULL AND is_primary IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT * FROM @tempTable WHERE typee = typee AND is_primary = is_primary
ELSE IF typee IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT * FROM @tempTable WHERE typee = typee
ELSE IF is_primary IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT * FROM @tempTable WHERE is_primary = is_primary
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM @tempTable
END
```

though I think this is not the best practice to do it.

### EDIT:

Based on the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553329/2674662), you could create the `query` into a string first, then execute it. Your `sp` should look like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testIfCondition`(IN countryId int(11),IN typee INT(11),IN is_primary INT(11),
out name VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT('select name from country where id = ', countryId);
    if typee <> 0 then
        SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' AND typee = ', typee);
    end if;
    if is_primary <> 0 then
        SET @query = CONCAT(@query, ' AND is_primary = ', is_primary);
    end if;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

You can look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/885bb/25) to see the execute query from the string.

Comment: Consider i have another  variable or column called is_primary, i need to check both typee and is_primary. Some times is_primary will come null or typee will come as null or both may come null. What to do for that condition. I cant write may else if. So in one query itself i need to check all. Please tell what to do for that !

Comment: I don't think you can do that in one query, but if you can do it like in my example at the top, you can update the `IF` condition, will update the answer.

Comment: I have big query with multiple columns to check. I cant write with mulitiple if conditions to check each column. if it like 'select * from table where id = 1 if is_primary ==0 then
and is_primary=0
end if; '
This is how am looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your update. Working fine for me !