# How to use string in IN clause in stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In my code, I am passing a string variable('4,5,6') to my stored procedure which exploded from this string(4,5,6-Name). I am using IN clause in stored procedure and I know that IN clause accept ('4','5','6') or simply (4,5,6) this type of data but I am unable to use it in my stored procedure. please help me if there is any other way to achieve it.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE kbm.report_site_transfer(IN siteid VARCHAR(50), IN datefrom VARCHAR (15), IN dateto VARCHAR (15))

SELECT
        * 
      FROM
        tbl_transfer
      WHERE
        tbl_transfer.siteNameID IN (siteid) AND (tbl_transfer.paymentDate BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto);
```

Comment: Whats the value of `site_id`

Comment: @Uchiha actually I am exploding a string (4,5,6-anyname) and exploded it with "-" seperator and want to use first value in IN clause (4,5,6) but when i checked the type in php, it is showing a string so i am unable to use in IN clause  in stored procedure

Comment: See this about dynamically creating & executing a query string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549619/mysql-dynamically-build-query-string-in-a-stored-procedure-based-on-logic. You would need to add the surrounding single quotes in the parameter you are passing.

Comment: @PaulF I checked it already but not working for me

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the string.

Comment: @PaulF I am exploding a string (4,5,6-anyname) and exploded it with "-" seperator and want to use first value in IN clause (4,5,6) but when i checked the type in php, it is showing a string so i am unable to use in IN clause in stored procedure. I checked my code it's working fine I only want to know how to use string in IN clause in my stored procedure

Comment: I have added some code as per the link I gave you as an answer because it formats better.

Answer (score 2):

This code also working fine. I used FIND_IN_SET function :

```
FIND_IN_SET(tbl_transfer.siteNameID, siteid)
```

Full code :

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE kbm.report_site_transfer(IN siteid VARCHAR(50), IN datefrom VARCHAR (15), IN dateto VARCHAR (15))

SELECT
    * 
  FROM
    tbl_transfer
  WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(tbl_transfer.siteNameID, siteid)  AND (tbl_transfer.paymentDate BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this as I gave you the link to - you create the entire query as a string & then execute as a prepared statement:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE kbm.report_site_transfer(IN siteid VARCHAR(50), IN datefrom VARCHAR (15), IN dateto VARCHAR (15))

Set @query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM tbl_transfer WHERE tbl_transfer.siteNameID IN (", siteid, ") AND (tbl_transfer.paymentDate BETWEEN ", datefrom, " AND ", dateto, ")";

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

If you wanted the single quoted version you could use this :

```
Set @query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM tbl_transfer WHERE tbl_transfer.siteNameID IN ('", REPLACE(siteid,",", "','"), "') AND (tbl_transfer.paymentDate BETWEEN ", datefrom, " AND ", dateto, ")";
```

Comment: Thanks PaulF, query running perfectly but I also found a way it's also giving the output as I wanted. but thank you so much for your efforts