# convert comma separated string values into integer values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a comma separated string variable v_combined_prodid .
But i wants to convert comma separated string variable to comma separated int value or in loop where we can update one table with where clause prodid as int.
we cant use FIND_IN_SET(prodid, v_combined_prodid )

we can use stored procedure.

```
DECLARE v_combined_prodid varchar(800);

set v_combined_prodid ='1,2,3,4,5';

below statement exactly requirement.

update mytable t set t.status=2
 WHERE prodid in (1,2,3,4,5)
 and t.status=0 ;
```

Comment: P Nayak, did the answer below help you? If so, you have the option of marking the answer as accepted. It's your choice. Marking your question with an accepted answer will give closure to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off creating a dynamic query and then execute it.

See [Mysql dynamically build query string in a stored procedure based on logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549619) for an example.

```
DECLARE v_combined_prodid varchar(800);

set v_combined_prodid ='1,2,3,4,5';

set @query = CONCAT(' update mytable t set t.status = 2 where prodid in ('
                    , v_combined_prodid
                    , ') and t.status = 0');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```