# MYSQL SELECT but with conditions

Tags: mysql, select, case

Is it possible within a MYSQL SELECT statement to include conditions dependent on user selection? Edited for clarity.
Something that does this:

```
IF user *does A* SELECT * FROM myTable
IF user *does B* SELECT colB, colC, colD FROM myTable
ELSE SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID < 5
```

Original Post references proprietary frontend but I just want to see if there is a solution in a MYSQL Query alone.

<s>I have a MYSQL Query that returns a filtered view of a table based on a dropdown selection of a column value. I want to include an option to *Return All* of the table if the dropdown *doesn't* match a value from the column or if the user selects 'Show All'. Something like this:</s>

Is there a way to use ELSE like this:

```
SELECT colA FROM mytable
WHERE *userChoice* = colA
ELSE SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Or, I think it can be done with a case statement but I can't figure out the syntax:

```
    CASE
        WHEN userPick = colA THEN SELECT colA FROM myTable
        WHEN userPick = colB THEN SELECT colB FROM myTable
        WHEN userPick = selectAll THEN SELECT * FROM myTable
        ELSE SELECT * FROM myTable
    END
```

I want to add a clause to the query that will allow me to return something else if the user *doesn't* select a distinct value from colA.
[image: Rough image of what I currently have.]

Comment: mysql does not have dropdowns so are you using something as well eg php?

Comment: Yes I'm using a frontend that accepts mysql queries

Comment: You should specify what framework or whatever you are using in your frontend

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is fixed and what is changing for the cases? Number of cols is changing (I guess from the example), but is the table the same? Are the where conditions the same? Are all others like ordering the same?

Comment: @gaborsch I already have the functionality to return a filtered table view when the user selects a distinct value from colA, ideally I want a clause within the same query to allow me to choose what is returned if they enter something that is not a distinct value from colA, hence the request for a condition in my SELECT query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (colA) LIKE '%SearchString%'
OR (SelectAll) LIKE '%SA%'
```

I found a workaround, I added a SelectAll column and referenced that in my SELECT query

Answer (score 2):

you need to build query string, check this thread [Mysql dynamically build query string in a stored procedure based on logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549619/mysql-dynamically-build-query-string-in-a-stored-procedure-based-on-logic)

with below query like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(input VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
SET @input = input;

if @input="asc" then
    SET @sort = " order by ActivityLogKey asc";
elseif @input = "desc" then
    SET @sort = " order by ActivityLogKey desc";
else
    SET @sort ="";
end if;

SET @query = CONCAT('select * from activitylog ',@sort,' limit 0, 5');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the number of columns if it's a compiled statement. A `select` statement should return the same number of columns.

What you can do is to return all possible columns, and use a union construct to enable the selects with a specific where condition. This way you can use different tables, different where conditions - even different columns, if your processing logic can handle it. The key thing is that all selects in a union must return the same number of columns, so you need to return `null` as placeholders. The first select must define all column aliases, especially when the value is null.

```
SELECT t1.colA, null as colB, null as colC
  FROM myTable t1
 where userPick = colA
UNION ALL
SELECT null, t2.colB, null
  FROM myTable t2
 where userPick = colB
   and t2.id < 5
UNION ALL
SELECT t3.colA, t3.colB, t3.colC
  FROM myTable t3
 where userPick <> colA AND userPick <> colB  -- this is the ELSE part
```

Note that you don't need the `userPick = selectAll` branch, because it is the same as the `ELSE` part.

Comment: Hi thanks, I didn't wish to change the number of columns, apologies I didn't show the whole version of the filtered tables in my rough sketch. I wanted a filtered return option in a select query with an option to clear filters/ select all if needed